# Did what I can to keep my website SEO friendly, yet newer websites are ranked better?

Tags: seo, google, google-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to increase a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google)

I have a website that gives information about weddings,
My site has been up for almost two years now, I designed it and programmed it entirely,
While developing my website I tried to keep it SEO-friendly, I read about SEO at random websites, read articles about it and such.

Nowadays my website is still quite bad with the "big" words such as "Wedding" (Not in english)

My budget for advertising is not the biggest, I am thinking of advertising with AdWords but I don't think that it really affects SEO, does it?

The thing is that about two months ago, I found a new website that does pretty much what my site does, it was after me in google's results, but suddenly started climbing up, now it's on the first page.
How does one do such a thing? I looked into the domain history, and is newer than mine as well.

I never thought that it's possible to go up so fast , 
I saw some companies that go around and say that you will be on the first / second page for sure if you pay them a nice amount of money, but I thought that I could skip this because as far as I heard SEO is not really controlled by these people,
 what they could do is just change a few things in my design to make it even more SEO-friendly, and maybe link to my site from random forums and websites.

Am I wrong though? can they really guarantee such a thing? Is there any "SEO Magic" that I dont know of?

I'd love to hear what you guys have to say about this and know more about how to improve my website's ranking

Thanks